# Edit custom UITableViewCell textView when didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, xcode

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

if(indexPath.row==0) {
//Edit the textView in this cell   
}
```

Is there a way to do this? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, you have a custom UITableViewCell with the

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextView* textView;
```

so, to appear the keyboard

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

       if(indexPath.row==0) {
          [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]textView]becomeFirstResponder];
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have added textview as a subview to cells contenview then you can try this

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

 for(int i=0;i<[[cell.contentView subviews] count];i++)
  {

    if([[[cell.contentView subviews] objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]])
    {
        [[[cell.contentView subviews] objectAtIndex:i] becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

}